# How to send XML Data to Sql Table

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

**I write some code to send xml data to sql table its working but i am trying send data to table creating Object of xml document.Without specifying the column of table.**

**My Code :-**

```
class Xml
    {
        //Function for Read Xml file and store into Sql table
        public void ReadXmlFileAndInsertIntoTable(string client, string xmlpath, string Connectionstring)
        {
            try
            {
                string connetionString = null;
                SqlConnection connection;
                SqlCommand command;
                SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                // XmlReader xmlFile;
                string sql = null;

                int product_ID = 0;
                string Product_Name = null;
                double product_Price = 0;

                connetionString = Connectionstring;
                connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

                //xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlpath, new XmlReaderSettings());
                //ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


                string xmlFile = xmlpath;
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                if (File.Exists(xmlFile))
                {
                    xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t Xml File Read Successfully");

                    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
                    XmlNodeList nodelist = node.ChildNodes;

                    //for (int j = 0; j < nodelist.Count; j++)
                    //    Console.WriteLine("{0}", nodelist[j].InnerText);

                    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file {0} could not be located", xmlFile);
                }

                connection.Open();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
                    Product_Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    product_Price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
                    sql = "insert into Product values(" + product_ID + ",'" + Product_Name + "'," + product_Price + ")";
                    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    adpter.InsertCommand = command;
                    adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connection.Close();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t Data Inserted Successfully...!!!");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }


    //Main Function
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t=====================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t My Application");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t=====================================================================");

            Console.WriteLine("\t 1. Try Simple XML Data Copy and store in Table");
            Console.WriteLine("\t 2. Exit Tool");

            Console.Write("\n\t Please Enter Your Response :- ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t Enter Client Name :- ");
                    string client = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t Enter XML Path :- ");
                    var xmlpath = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t Enter Connctionstring :- ");
                    var Connectionstring = Console.ReadLine();

                    Xml xml = new Xml();
                    xml.ReadXmlFileAndInsertIntoTable(client, xmlpath, Connectionstring);
                    break;


                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t Please enter valid response...!!!");
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have an error? What is the error?

Comment: See msdn for format of INSERT : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

Comment: There is no error. in my table there are several child node how can i map this scenario it this code .